# Can I associate Liferay Listener for my custom code?

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

I am using **Liferay 6.1 CE** for Portal Application development.

I am new to Liferay, so please excuse if my question is wrong.

My query is with respect to Listeners in liferay, I see that Liferay Listeners are limited to predefined core portal model like journal, users, ... etc. (Correct me if I am wrong)

I want to call a Listener's `onAfterCreate` method (that is after creation of `User` is done)

In our Aplication for creating user, we have a seperate `createUser.jsp`, and on click of the submit button, it is stored in one of the tables called `Virte_Users` table in database.

Please let me know, is it possible to associate a liferay Listener in this case?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you also adding the data from `createUser.jsp` to liferay's `User_` table?

Answer (score 0):

You can not use default listener but you can add your own for a particular model.

For e.g.,

You can have your listener extend `BaseModelListener<User>` like,

```
MyUserListener extends BaseModelListener<User>
```

Please check source of `UserListener` and put the below property in `portal-ext.properties`:

```
 # You can add a listener for a specific class by setting the property
 # "value.object.listener" with a list of comma delimited class names that
 # implement com.liferay.portal.model.ModelListener. These classes are pooled
 # and reused and must be thread safe.

    value.object.listener.com.liferay.portal.model.User=com.liferay.portal.model.UserListener,<b>com.my.user.MyUserListener</b>
```